# When Run Emulator: GL error while resizing: 0x506 (ignored)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-2.2, java-8

I'm PHP Developer and newbie to android platform, I've install below mention details,

```
1.jdk1.8
2.android 2.2 32bit
3.node js.
```

FYI, I've created new project using command line, simple project name(test) and when try to run below mention errors getting,..

```
C:\Users\Jtechusers\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Galaxy_Nexus_API_23_5
Could not load func glBindFramebuffer
Could not load func glGenFramebuffers
Could not load func glFramebufferTexture2D
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
Could not load func glCheckFramebufferStatus
Could not load func glDeleteFramebuffers
Could not load func glIsRenderbuffer
Could not load func glBindRenderbuffer
Could not load func glDeleteRenderbuffers
Could not load func glGenRenderbuffers
Hax is enabled
Could not load func glRenderbufferStorage
Hax ram_size 0x20000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
Could not load func glGetRenderbufferParameteriv
Could not load func glFramebufferRenderbuffer
Could not load func glGenerateMipmap
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
GL error while resizing: 0x506 (ignored)
GL error while resizing: 0x506 (ignored)
Renderer error: failed to create/resize pbuffer!!
GL error while resizing: 0x506 (ignored)
GL error while resizing: 0x506 (ignored)
GL error while resizing: 0x506 (ignored)
```

Note :

In the AVD Manager,

> Nexus 5X : 5.2 1080x1920dpi, 
>   Marshmallow : Android 6.0 x86 ,
>   Ram : 512mb,
>   VM Heap : 64mb(if change 1536 ive getting warning so ive using 512),
>   Internal Storage : 768,

Ive spending more time for this is.

Kindly support me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this problem for myself once I changed my emulator device from a screen size that was larger than my computer monitor to one that was smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem using this setting

[image]